# How can i use Android Beam in Asus Zenfone 5?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, asus-zenfone-5, android-beam

I have just upgraded my Asus Zenfone 5 to Lollipop from Kitkat....After successfull upgradation i found all features.But i am unable to find NFC to start Android Beam feature.
Is it supported ?I have upgraded through ZenTalk...

Comment: Is it not under "Settings -> Wireless & Networks"?

Comment: No it is not their

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't; the ZenFone 5 [does not have NFC](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/asus-zenfone-5-1205).  (No mention on [the official specs page](https://www.asus.com/Phone/ZenFone_5_A500CG/specifications/) either.)